# Streams and event loop - do data handlers always fire on next tick?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams, nodejs-stream

Say I have a readable stream, like so:

```
const strm = fs.createReadStream(file);
strm.on('data', function onData(d){});
```

my question is, does the `onData` callback fire in the next tick of the event loop? Or is it possible for the `onData` handler to be called twice in the same tick of the event loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data handlers can fire multiple times in the same tick of the event loop, see:

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1222

> Yes:

```
const stream = require('stream'); 
const readable = new stream.Readable({read(){}}); 
readable.on('data', () => console.log('data')); 
process.nextTick(() => console.log('next tick'));
readable.push('foo'); 
readable.push('foo');
```

> Output:
>
> data  data  next tick